# Reducing multiple arrays into one array in Swift and Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I'm looking to create a function that will allow me to pull a list of more friends based on my current list of friends. I'm starting with pulling my current list of friends, and for each of those friends, I pull their list of friends and append it into an array. However, my output right now is something like ["friendId1","friendId2"]["friendId1","friendId2","friendId3","friendId4"] and I'd like it to just show the second line ["friendId1","friendId2","friendId3","friendId4"]

```
func fetchOtherFriends(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {


    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("friends").child(currentUser).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

        // Iterate through all the children:

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {


            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let userId = value?["userId"] as? String ?? ""


            Database.database().reference().child("friends").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

                // Iterate through all the children:

                for child1 in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {


                    let value1 = child1.value as? NSDictionary

                    let userId1 = value1?["userId"] as? String ?? ""

                    self.otherfriendsArray.append(userId1)

                    completion(self.otherfriendsArray)

                }         
            })   
        }  
    })     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you can use **flatmap**.

**Input :**

```
let friendList = [["friend1","friend2"],["friend3","friend4"]]
```

**Solution:**

```
let result = friendList.flatMap{ $0 }
```

**Output:**

```
["friend1", "friend2", "friend3", "friend4"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the friendList is not set as a multidimensional array right now. It's simply ["friend1","friend2"] (next line) ["friend1","friend2","friend3","friend4"] since it's they're looping through multiple current friends. Not sure how to just use the second line if that makes sense.